# Flutter streamSnapshot.data.docs not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream

Trying to grab my stream snapshot length but for some reason the .docs isn't working. It says that docs cant be called on an Object, but I dont see why it would read my streamSnapshot as an Object when it should be a stream.

```
return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('chats/khgvkhvfkftkh/messages')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (ctx, streamSnapshot) {
          if (streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          final documents =
              streamSnapshot.data.docs.length;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: documents.length, //does not work due to error in declaration of documents
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `documents` to the **length** of the `docs` property

```
final documents = streamSnapshot.data.docs.length;
```

So when you later do `documents.length`, that's `streamSnapshot.data.docs.length.length`, which indeed doesn't exist.

Given the variable name, I expect you want to set `documents` to just:

```
final documents = streamSnapshot.data.docs;
```

Comment: Hey Frank! While you were absolutely right and that would have been my next error if my code ever made it there haha, but i seemed to have fixed it by declaring <AsyncSnapshot> when calling streamSnapshot in my streambuilder. Thanks for being part of my first question on Stack!

Answer (score 0):

```
return Scaffold(
//Just change the type of streamBuilder from object to dynamic, it will solve the error.
      body: StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('chats/k4dtLMCeacmpFMBf8sA9/messages')
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (ctx, streamSnapshot) {
            if (streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: const Text('This Works'),
              ),
            );
          }),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are meeting this challenge for the first time, the Solution is to define your StreamBuilder builder property as follows

```
   return Scaffold(
  body: StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Add your collection specific url')
        .snapshots(),
    builder:(ctx, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>streamSnapshot){ //Change here
      if(streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
     return ListView.builder(
        itemCount:streamSnapshot.data.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index)=>Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: const Text('This works')
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).